# Storing in JSON if a div is hidden or not

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to make divs show up or hide depending on what a JSON variable contains. I use JQuery for that.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var globalswitchNumber;

    $.getJSON('database.json', function(data) {
        var database = data.projects;


        function galleryshowUp() {
            $('#galleryone').attr('src', database[globalswitchNumber].galleryone, function() {
                if (database[globalswitchNumber].galleryonedisplay == 'showit') {
                    $("#galleryone").show();
                } else {
                    $("#galleryone").hide();
                }
            });
            $('#galleryonelink').attr('href', database[globalswitchNumber].galleryonelink);


            $('#gallerytwo').attr('src', database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwo, function() {
                if (database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwodisplay == 'showit') {
                    $("#gallerytwo").show();
                } else {
                    $("#gallerytwo").hide();
                }
            });
            $('#gallerytwolink').attr('href', database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwolink);
        }

        $('#irbis').on('click', function() {
            globalswitchNumber = 0;
            galleryshowUp();
        });


    });
});
```

And here is what I have in my JSON file:

```
 {  
   "projects":[  
      {  
         "galleryone":"img/previews/3_1_1.jpg",
         "galleryonelink":"img/original/3_1_1.jpg",
         "galleryonedisplay":"hideit",

         "gallerytwo":"img/previews/3_1_2.jpg",
         "gallerytwolink":"img/original/3_1_2.jpg",
         "gallerytwodisplay":"showit"
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is html I try to insert it into:

```
<a id="galleryonelink" target="_blank" href=""><img id="galleryone" src="" class="previewing"></a>
<a id="gallerytwolink" target="_blank" href=""><img id="gallerytwo" src="" class="previewing"></a>
```

And CSS styling for previewing:

```
.previewing{

    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style:none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
    animation: fadein 2s;

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}


.previewing:hover{ 
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

In result all of my divs just show up, none get hidden. What could be wrong here?

Comment: you should be getting error since `$(window).load(function() {` is not closed.

Comment: can you show your html.

Comment: Updated with html and css. If statement doesn't do anything for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it by taking if statement out of callback function.

```
$('#galleryone').attr('src', database[globalswitchNumber].galleryone);  
if (database[globalswitchNumber].galleryonedisplay == 'showit'){$("#galleryone").show();}else {$("#galleryone").hide();}
$('#galleryonelink').attr('href', database[globalswitchNumber].galleryonelink);                          


$('#gallerytwo').attr('src', database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwo);                              
if (database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwodisplay == 'showit'){$("#gallerytwo").show();}else {$("#gallerytwo").hide();}
$('#gallerytwolink').attr('href', database[globalswitchNumber].gallerytwolink);
```